# Insert bigquery query result to mysql

Tags: google-bigquery

In one of my PHP application, I need to show a report based on the aggregate data, which is fetched from BigQuery. I am planning to execute the queries using a PHP cron job then insert data to MySQL table from which the report will fetch data. Is there any better way of doing this like directly insert the data to MySQL without an application layer in between ?

Also I am interested in real time data, but the daily cron only update data once and there will be some mismatch of the counts with actual data if I check it after some time. If I run hourly cron jobs, I am afraid the data reading charges will be high as I am processing a dataset which is 20GB. Also my report cannot be fetched fro Bigquery itself and it needs to have data from MySQL database.

Comment: why don't you just do your report directly off the data in BigQuery instead of exporting it and importing into MySQL?

Comment: How large do you expect the results to be? Is there a particular reason you need to cache the results in MySQL (for example -- are you doing additional transformations on a smaller set of your data?). If your results are both modestly sized and don't require siginificant transformation, I'd just cache them in memcache, RAM, or a flat file within your PHP app.